# Unable to Retrieve Data from API in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, dio

I tried to show data by using reqres API: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 in my flutter app but it doesn't show any single data in here, i make user.response.dart by copying Get List User reqres response and convert it to Json to Dart

## **user_response.dart**

```
class UserResponse {
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  UserResponse(
      {this.page,
      this.perPage,
      this.total,
      this.totalPages,
      this.data,
      this.support});

  UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support =
        json['support'] != null ? new Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.support != null) {
      data['support'] = this.support!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Data({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    return data;
  }
}

class Support {
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Support({this.url, this.text});

  Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}
```

## **profile_repository.dart**

```
import 'package:autoduck_state2/domain/auth/model/login_request.dart';
import 'package:autoduck_state2/domain/auth/model/login_response.dart';
import 'package:autoduck_state2/domain/core/user/model/user_response.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ProfileRepository {
  Dio _dio = Dio();

  //Either digunakan untuk mengembalikan data left atau right,
  //Jika data salah maka akan mengembalikan String,Jika data benar maka akan mengembalikan UserResponse
  Future<Either<String, UserResponse>> getAllUserData(
      {required LoginRequest loginRequest}) async {
    Response _response;

    try {
      _response = await _dio.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
          data: loginRequest.toJson());
      //Jadi pada awal kita minta string, pada akhir dikasi string
      UserResponse _userResponse = UserResponse.fromJson(_response.data);
      return right(_userResponse);
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      //error yang dihasilkan oleh dio
      print(
          "DioException: ${e.response?.statusCode}, ${e.response?.statusMessage}");
      String errorMessage = e.response!.data.toString();

      // if(e.type == DioExceptionType.badResponse) {

      // }
      switch (e.type) {
        case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.badCertificate:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.badResponse:
          errorMessage = e.response!.data['error'];
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.cancel:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.connectionError:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.unknown:
          // TODO: Handle this case.
          break;
      }
      return left(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

## **home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:autoduck_state2/application/profile/bloc/profileb_bloc.dart';
import 'package:autoduck_state2/domain/auth/model/login_response.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key, required this.loginResponse}) : super(key: key);

  final LoginResponse loginResponse;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ProfilebBloc()..add(ProfilebEvent.getAllUserData()),
      child: BlocConsumer<ProfilebBloc, ProfilebState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          //maybeMap untuk mengambil sedikit data
          state.maybeMap(
            orElse: () {},
            isLoading: (value) {
              print("Is loading");
            },
            isSuccess: (value) {
              print(value.userResponse.toJson());
            },
          );
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return state.maybeMap(
            orElse: () => homePageError(),
            isLoading: (e) => homePageLoading(),
            isSuccess: (value) => homePageScaffold(),
            isError: (value) => homePageError(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold homePageError() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Something error"),
          Text("Something error"),
          Text("Something error"),
          Text("Something error"),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.replay)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold homePageLoading() => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );

  Scaffold homePageScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.loginResponse.token ?? "No Token")),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("nama"),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to fix my code quickly like atleast 12 hours after asking this

Comment: also add the error which you get when you call the api

Comment: check the Api Response (print response). are you getting the Proper Response and if your are getting the response check if it's getting formatted properly check _userResponse to see if response got converted of not.

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal it shows an error "Something wrong" which i made in method homePageError()

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if your server has a valid SSL certificate, if your not sure, first add httpOverrides to your main and check if the request works, if it works then the problem is your server certificate

```
import 'dart:io';


    class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
    
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      }
    }
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    }
```

Comment: it shows an error "Something wrong" which i made in method homePageError() from home_page.dart

Comment: What i suggest try removing try{ }catch(e){} and check your debug console while you run the request. the problem is not the request but your model is getting json data without wrong data types or null values that throws errors internally in the model or you have an  exception that is not raised during the catch. try check the try block is the one being executed or catch block

Comment: it still didn't see any change bro

Comment: Okay i have checked your code and Endpoint response, you need to use Future builder. let me post a full answer  to your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your looking for is this

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class UserResponse {
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  UserResponse(
      {this.page,
      this.perPage,
      this.total,
      this.totalPages,
      this.data,
      this.support});

  UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support =
        json['support'] != null ? new Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.support != null) {
      data['support'] = this.support!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Data({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    return data;
  }
}

class Support {
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Support({this.url, this.text});

  Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late Future<UserResponse?> usersFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    usersFuture = getAllUsers();
    super.initState();
  }



  var dio = Dio();
  Future<UserResponse?> getAllUsers() async {
    var response = await dio.request(
      'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
      options: Options(
        method: 'GET',
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      UserResponse _userResponse = UserResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      return _userResponse;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: usersFuture,
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          // Displaying LoadingSpinner to indicate waiting state
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                ]);
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            } else {
              // PagingMovieModel? wfmovies = snapshot.data;
              UserResponse? users = snapshot.data;
              ///////////////////

              return users == null
                  ? const Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                              "Failed to get data from server, please check your internet connection"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : ListView(
                      children: List.generate(
                        users.data!.length,
                        (index) {
                          Data user = users.data![index];
                          return ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                child: Image.network(user.avatar ??
                                    "https://fakeimg.pl/200x200"),
                              ),
                              title: Text("${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}"),
                              subtitle: Text(user.email ?? ""));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
            }
          } else {
            return const Text(
              "Something went wrong, please try again laiter",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if you want to add new user data  the future incase your handling paging you must do it like this

```
 UserResponse? userresponse = await getAllUsers(newpageno);
    if(userresponse != null){
    List<Data> newusers = userresponse.data;
     usersFuture.then((value) => value!..results.addAll(newusers));
    }
```

The results must look like this

[image: screenshot]